# Why did they bring Starro into the "The Suicide Squad" plot?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

From the Wikipedia article on [Starro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starro), I learned
that the Justice League team defeated Starro by coating it by quicklime:

> Eventually, they are stopped by the superheroes **Aquaman, the Flash,
> Green Lantern, Martian Manhunter and Wonder Woman**. The heroes defeat
> **Starro by coating it with quicklime**, which nullifies the entity's
> abilities.

Why did they bring Starro into the *The Suicide Squad* plot?

Comment: Nothing in your question seems to give a good reason why they wouldn't.  Why not?

Comment: @Exal I think the reason, although not stated, is that in the comics it is a JL villain rather than anything related to SS or the heroes in the film.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [James Gunn](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2570702/james-gunn-explains-chose-starro-the-suicide-squads-big-villain):

> I just, I wanted a major DC villain that is a major DC villain that people wouldn't expect to be in a movie. And I've always loved Starro. I mean, as a kid, I found Starro completely terrifying. The idea of this giant starfish with one big eye that shoots these things out of him that take over people's brains, like those old pictures with Superman with him on his face. Always scared the shit out of me. So, it was about taking something that was completely, mind you, ridiculous, that looks, putting him in a setting that is the gritty streets of Colón, Panama, and then allowing him to do his scary business, but he's also completely outrageous. And so, that mix of things appealed to my aesthetic.

[Also](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2566767/why-the-suicide-squad-using-starro-one-of-its-villains-james-gunn):

> Starro is hilarious because he’s ridiculous. He’s a giant, cerulean blue starfish, but he’s also fucking terrifying. When I was a kid I thought that was the scariest thing of all time… and I think that exemplifies what this movie is: it is ridiculous and it’s also terrifying, and serious. So he works really well as the villain of the movie—as one of the villains, actually.

Comment: Who knew that Starro was a *major* D.C. villain?

Comment: @Buzz Well, he's large, powerful (a world-ending threat), and meaningful (being, as mentioned, one of the first JL foes ever).  One comic I read recently had a discussion about the foes that the League has defeated, and the heavy hitters depicted are Starro, Despero, and Amazo.  (Boy, we need to come up with more original names)